# Python - Converting urllib to requests

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I'm writing code to access the MS365 API and the Python code example uses urllib. I want to instead use requests but I'm not sure how urllib translates into requests as my attempts of doing so have failed.

The code example can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/run-advanced-query-sample-python?view=o365-worldwide#get-token

```
import json
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

tenantId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' # Paste your own tenant ID here
appId = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' # Paste your own app ID here
appSecret = '22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222' # Paste your own app secret here

url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token" % (tenantId)

resourceAppIdUri = 'https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com'

body = {
    'resource' : resourceAppIdUri,
    'client_id' : appId,
    'client_secret' : appSecret,
    'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'
}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(body).encode("utf-8")

req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
jsonResponse = json.loads(response.read())
aadToken = jsonResponse["access_token"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying @BeRT2me's answer has made this work.

```
import requests

tenantId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' # Paste your own tenant ID here
appId = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' # Paste your own app ID here
appSecret = '22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222' # Paste your own app secret here

url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token" % (tenantId)

resourceAppIdUri = 'https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com'

data = {
    'resource' : resourceAppIdUri,
    'client_id' : appId,
    'client_secret' : appSecret,
    'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'
}

response = requests.post(url=url, data=data)
jsonResponse = response.json()
aadToken = jsonResponse["access_token"]
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, this should work the same:

```
import requests

tenantId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' # Paste your own tenant ID here
appId = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111' # Paste your own app ID here
appSecret = '22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222' # Paste your own app secret here

url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token" % (tenantId)

resourceAppIdUri = 'https://api.securitycenter.microsoft.com'

params = {
    'resource' : resourceAppIdUri,
    'client_id' : appId,
    'client_secret' : appSecret,
    'grant_type' : 'client_credentials'
}

response = requests.get(url, params)
jsonResponse = response.json()
aadToken = jsonResponse["access_token"]
```

Comment: The content of this response is an HTML page saying the endpoint only accepts POST. 

Changing it to requests.post(url=url, data=params) has made it work.

Comment: Ah, interesting, didn't realize it was a post request. Glad you got it to work!